# replicating cached data between multiple servers

Tags: java, caching, jakarta-ee, jboss, memcached

I'm working on an application which was, till now, running on JBoss AS on a single server. Now there is a requirement for failover for which we're adding another server and creating a JBoss cluster. Here is the problem:

Till now the application was using a Hashmap to store about 2 million records that we fetched from the database.
Now i have to replicate this data to the second node (there maybe more nodes added in the future).
The data that we need to store is more likely going to be something like 5 million records now.

I just want to have an opinion on what's the best approach for storing this key/value type data and replicate it on all the server nodes.

I've been thinking if Redis or memcached would be an appropriate solution? How about JBoss Cache, I know it is distributed cache and does replication to all nodes in the cluster.

Here are things i'm MOST worried about:

1. effect on performance - replication could cause network latency data
2. quality - want to avoid working with stale data  impact on memory -
3. once the data is loaded in HashMap/Cache it should not expire. There maybe some additions or deletions of records and these changes will have to be replicated on all the nodes.
4. scalability - as i mentioned ... more nodes could be added

Any thoughts on this are highly appreciated.

Comment: Replication consistency! Aaargh! Pick up some middlewares :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working in a Java environment I would suggest you to have a look at hazelcast (http://www.hazelcast.com/). We are using it to synchronize several portal servers and it works very nice!

Comment: hi csupnig. Did you compare hazelcast with other alternative caches such as JBoss Cache? What is the distinct advantage of hazelcast for which you are using it?

Comment: We used JCSCache before and decided to switch to hazelcast because it also supports sending messages to other server instances, further improving the syncrhonization capabilities...